# Eclipse ignores exclusion patterns on Mac OS X

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I have an Eclipse project that needs to exclude certain files from

```
src/main/resources
```

to prevent them being copied to target/classes

On my Windows PC, I exclude these by adding an exclusion patterns to my build path for src/main/resources:

```
**/myfile.properties
```

After recently switching to Mac OS Mountain Lion and Eclipse Juno I find that this setting is being ignored. I've basically tried excluding by exact path in various forms, **/myfile.properties etc. Whatever I do, on refresh, it gets added to my target/classes

Does anybody have this same issue or know a way around this?

Comment: Why are they in src/main/resources if they don't belong in the generated artifact?

Comment: I have a number of variables in myfile.properties that are replaced by either production, test or dev relevant values by maven. Since I don't build everything with maven in eclipse, the replacement doesn't occur and I exclude these so I can manage a local dev version manually

Comment: Ew; instead just provide a startup property/etc to determine which file to use. IMO it's a bad idea to rely on an IDE to create a correct build--even if it's *just* you that will *ever* touch the code, you may switch IDEs. Make it more robust.

Comment: Hmm, I see your point but it sort of defeats the purpose of having a singular properties file that may change over time. Also, eclipse IS my dev environment and it should just filter those out

Comment: But you already *don't* have a single property file that changes over time. And I understand that Eclipse is your Dev environment *today*: when you switch to IntelliJ it won't be. Or Jimmy the contractor brings in net beans.

Comment: I disagree but I might have found a potential reason for this problem. I'm using various builders
AspectJ Builder
Faceted Project Validation Builder
Validation
Spring Project Builder
Maven Project Builder

I'll bet one of those is responsible for ignoring the exclusion pattern

Comment: So, you're arguing that relying on the vagaries of IDE builds isn't a problem after asking a question about a problem with relying on the vagaries of an IDE build? Interesting approach. Relying on an IDE-specific build mechanism is broken for at least a couple reasons.

Comment: I disagree with your IDE flexibility requirement. I don't think IDE building is vague, but it can be complex given the various builders that can be involved. But bottom line: the actual issue at hand: files being included by Eclipse that should have been excluded: that's something you cannot help with right? I will agree to disagree with you then

Comment: That's not what "vagaries" means, and you ran into *precisely* the kind of problem that relying on IDE builds creates, and that's even before recognizing the possibility that you, or someone else, might wish to use a different IDE. Not quite sure how you don't see that, but ok. I *did* help you--I told you to change the mechanism to avoid the kinds of problems relying on IDE build present. Like this one. Good luck!